# Configure Git/TFS remote repository to two local repositories

Tags: angular, git, tfs, version-control, node-modules

We've been building an `Angular 6` web app . One of the front end frameworks/tools we're using throughout the app to create grids is `Wijmo`. Unfortunately, the version of `Wijmo` we're using is a `-rc` (release-candidate) build, something that is not suitable for production. We're relatively deep into the project and from all tests, changing the version might break some things.

So I'd like to create a new local repo and connect it to the original remote repo. So the remote repo will now be pointing to two local repositories: the original local repository w/ the `-rc` `Wijmo` version, and my new local repo with the updated `Wijmo` version. Is this possible w/ `Git`? So far, every time I go into the new local project and try to connect it with the original remote repo, the local project switches back to the initial local project that was already linked to the remote repo.

I guess one issue here may be that our `node_modules` folder is not currently included in our git repos. Thus my need to create an entirely new local repo to house a new `node_modules` folder. Perhaps I should just include `node_modules` in the git repo - that way I can stay in the original local repo and just create a new local branch whenever I want a new instance of the `node_modules` folder?

Just wondering what your approaches might be.

**[edit]** Another option may be copying the contents of the remote repo to a new remote repo, and connecting new remote repo to new local repo. But I'm unsure of how to copy one remote repo's contents to a new remote repo

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so, why you can't just create a branch and update there version `Wijmo`? You will have 2 copies of app, one in **master with -rc version** and one in **your branch with updated version**. About **node_modules** if you use **npm** you should have `package-lock.json` where you have all dependencies with all specific versions locked, so when you do `npm install` it will just download and install all dependencies from `package-lock.json`. So in master you will have `package-lock.json` with -rc and in your branch with updated version, and that's it. You do not need to check-in your node_modules, because `package-lock.json` basically describes all your dependencies and they will be restored everywhere equally. Afterwards, if everything works, you can just merge your branch into master. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for this - but I'm unsure. Because in the new branch, if I update the `package-lock.json` version of `Wijmo`, the `node_modules` folder will still have the `-rc` version inside of the `node_modules/wijmo` folder. Are you saying that in the new project I just need to run `npm install wijmo version whatever`, and only the wijmo version listed in `package-lock.json` will be installed, and the `node_modules` `-rc` version number will be ignored?

Comment: Also, will `npm install wijmo version whatever` overwrite the `-rc` version listed in `node_modules`, or will `node_modules` be left alone?

Comment: When you change branch, you will have new version of `wijmo` in `package-lock.json` however in `node_modules` you will have an old one, but you just need to run `npm install` which will update your `node_modules` versions to what you have in `package-lock.json` and that is it.

Comment: During deployment it's not an issue because you run `npm install` each time there (so you each time update your `node_modules` to what you have in `package-lock.json`), and in staging envs and production you always will have packages versions that specified in `package-lock.json`. Locally, thought, you need to run `npm install` manually each time you have your `package-lock.json` updated.

Comment: Ok, that was I was afraid of. So if I run `npm install`, `node_modules` will be changed based on what versions I specify in `package-lock.json`. I was afraid of this since if the new version of `Wijmo` breaks stuff, I'd like to be able to easily revert back to `-rc`. But you're saying that if I want to revert back, all I need to do is change the version number in `package-lock.json` back to the old `-rc`, run `npm install` and `node_modules` will revert back to the `-rc` version?

Comment: That is correct, and you even do not need to change `package-lock.json` **manually**, you just need to `run npm install wijmo@1.0.24-rc` and it will automatically update your `package-lock.json` to contain that version

Comment: Thank you so much - I'll come back and mark this as correct answer once I try in the near future.